# How To Use Threading on RxJava?

Tags: java, multithreading, rx-java

```
        Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<Integer>() {

        public void call(final Subscriber<? super Integer> obs) {
            new Thread(){
                public void run(){
                    obs.onNext(1);
                }
            }.start();
            new Thread(){
                public void run(){
                    obs.onNext(2);
                }
            }.start();
            new Thread(){
                public void run(){
                    obs.onNext(3);
                }
            }.start();
            obs.onCompleted();
        }
    }).subscribe(new Subscriber<Integer>(){

        public void onCompleted() {
            System.out.println("Complete");

        }

        public void onError(Throwable arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public void onNext(Integer arg0) {
            System.out.println(arg0);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    });
```

As you see , I want to do multi-threading on Java with RxJava

I've studied many resources on Google , but most of them are for Android

Can anybody tell what is the easiest way to implement it ?

I think my code is a little :<

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, it's a bit unclear what you're asking, but it is worthwhile to at least have a cursory read over the Observable class, as it has a lot of methods that will make your life easier. For example, your code roughly translates to:

```
 Observable
 .just(1,2,3)
 .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
 .zipWith(Observable.interval(1000,1000,TimeUnit.milliseconds),
     (item, pos) -> item)
 .doOnCompleted(() -> System.out.println("Complete");
 .subscribe(item -> System.out.println(item));
```

However, you first need to be clear on what do you want to do - can you put it to words?

Comment: I want  to start many tasks at same time , but they might take different time to finish.    I just want to know  how to implement multi-threading with RxJava

Comment: Then just skip the `zipWith` call.

Comment: The beauty of Rx is that you don't have to write any multi-threaded code anymore. It's all abstracted into [schedulers](http://reactivex.io/documentation/scheduler.html). You can get instances via the [`Schedulers`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/schedulers/Schedulers.html) class. Use them in your operator sequence with operators like [`observeOn`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#observeOn(rx.Scheduler)) and [`subscribeOn`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#subscribeOn(rx.Scheduler)) or in static methods such as `timer`, `interval`, etc.